# Eliminate npm "update available" message

Tags: npm

It seems that more recent versions of npm now produce:

[image]

I rely on my Linux (Ubuntu) package manager to make decisions about when to update node and npm. Is there a way to turn this check off?

`npm config ls -l` seems to have nothing related to this and in `.npm` in my home dir there appears to be no preferences file.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

To disable notifier just run:

```
npm config set update-notifier false
```

As Dem Pilafian mentioned - it will add `update-notifier=false` to `~/.npmrc`

To see the current value you need this line

```
npm config get update-notifier
```

Read more about npm config here https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config

Comment: Is it known whether this or other solutions disable npm checking for updates entirely?  I don't mind (and would actually welcome) if it checks when I explicitly run `npm`, but I definitely object to it randomly phoning home whenever I open a terminal.

Comment: @Kev Not sure about that, but `npm config edit --global` opens the config file in an editor.

Comment: To my surprise, the `npm config set update-notifier false` command creates the `.npmrc` if it has not existed yet. So you do not have to search for the file to edit it yourself; it will be created for you.

Comment: The fun part is that running `npm config ...` or any other `npm` command for the first time will show "npm notice" so to avoid it in the first place one can do `echo "update-notifier=false" >> ~/.npmrc` instead

Answer (score 26):

This was annoying me as well, but there's absolutely no information about it anywhere.

Looking through the code, I've found that the update-notifier-module used by npm has actually a couple of ways to turn it off.

The best one is probably the special config-file located at `~/.config/configstore/update-notifier-npm.json` (just search for `update-notifier-npm.json`). Inside it, simply set "optOut" to true.

The other ways to disable it would be setting an environment-variable called "NO_UPDATE_NOTIFIER" or using the argument "--no-update-notifier"

Comment: Putting this here for reference https://www.npmjs.com/package/update-notifier#user-settings

Comment: `NO_UPDATE_NOTIFIER` doesn't seem to cut it, any more (npm 7.19, 7.20.3) though the docs linked to by Andrew show it should. `--no-update-notifier` works, but note that it doesn't cover inner `npm` tasks you might call from within the `package.json`.

Answer (score 16):

[update-notifier=false](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#update-notifier)

in `.npmrc` file seems to do the trick since NPM [v6.2.0-next.0 (2018-06-28)](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/CHANGELOG.md#v620-next0-2018-06-28).

Comment: The command `$ npm config set update-notifier false` will add the line `update-notifier=false` to `~/.npmrc` for you.

Comment: Thank you @DemPilafian for the solution that is both easy and sensible.

Answer (score 8):

For newer (v7+) npm you can use `export NPM_CONFIG_UPDATE_NOTIFIER=false` to disable via environment

https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/1632

Comment: NPM_CONFIG_UPDATE_NOTIFIER=false works.

Answer (score 1):

if you are to parse the npm command output, one option is to format the output, such as "--json true", "npm list --json true", npm will honour the argument and hide the upgrade message.

Answer (score -1):

I created an ansible task that sets `optOut` to `true` and `lastUpdateCheck` to the current date.

In `tasks/main.yml`:

```
---

- name: copy update-notifier-npm template file to disable checking for npm updates
  template: src=update-notifier-npm.j2 dest=~/.config/configstore/update-notifier-npm.json
```

In `templates/update-notifier-npm.j2`:

```
{
    "optOut": true,
    "lastUpdateCheck": {{ ansible_date_time.epoch }}000
}
```

The logic that creates this file in the `update-notifier` package is here:

https://github.com/yeoman/update-notifier/blob/3fdb21876aa391f9bc7dc35b7d81151677fb533d/index.js#L53