# How to prevent ionic periodically polling registry.npmjs.org?

Tags: ionic-framework, auto-update

After recently updating nodejs to v9.5.0 as part of bumping dependencies for an ionic project I am seeing periodic connection attempts to registry.npmjs.org even when ionic is not running.

The moment when I get the connection alert (from a firewall app) I can see that there are 3 `node` and `npm` processes in the Activity Monitor, but even after I kill them (with `pkill node`) after about 10 or 20 minutes I see again `node` processes attempting to connect to registry.npmjs.org.

The actual command that I see being run with `ionic` as the parent process:

```
81830 /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.5.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/update-notifier/check.js {"pkg":{"name":"npm","version":"5.6.0"}}
```

Is there a way to control this periodic update check by ionic?

Comment: What command, specifically, is running in the background (`ps aux | grep 'node\|npm'`)?

Comment: @JordanRunning: I added the output of `pgrep -fil npm` to the original question.

Comment: Further investigation revealed that the parent process of `npm` is `ionic` which in turn was started by `launchd`. This is very strange because I don't have any terminal windows open with ionic running. Don't see the point why `ionic` needs to run in the background while it is not explicitly launched. In any case this looks like an issue with `ionic` and not with `node/npm`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46800717/eliminate-npm-update-available-message

Comment: Thanks for the link! I set `optOut=true`. Still need to look into why `ionic` triggers npm in the background.

Comment: it isn't ionic specific problem... I have same issue but I never used ionic on my machine. try to turn off update-notifier by config setting: `npm config set update-notifier false` after that you can kill task or restart your computer and not view again

Comment: @sarkiroka: that's exactly what I did, the issue is indeed `npm`-related and not specific to ionic.

Comment: @ccpizza, after I modified the global npm settings, the updater never seen